# CSS: Overwrite bootstrap when using sprockets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a rails/bootstrap app. My application.css.scss.erb "manifest" file currently simply includes bootstrap, the scaffolds css, and my custom file "dryclean.css":

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import "scaffolds.css.scss";
@import "dryclean.css"
```

Unfortunately, bootstrap is overwriting my custom logic, despite my stuff being further down the import list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.css.scss:
/*
*= require_self
*= require dryclean
*= require scaffolds
*/

@import "bootstrap_override"; 
/* if you do not need override boostrap behaviour, just import boostrap here  */



bootstrap_override.css.scss:
@import "bootstrap";

/* Your bootstrap extentions goes here */
```

Actually you should override every style sheet you use within your app. That gives you the opportunity to have compatible code between bootstrap versions. Consider a case when some style sheet in newer boostrap version changes, for instance `.btn` becomes `.button`. Then you have to change it the whole app. On the other hand, you may deal with it only within your css.scss:

```
 .btn {
   @extend .btn;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise there was such a learning curve to move to .scss style imports.